# Java regex group stops at first result

Tags: java, regex

My regex is (without java escapes) `//(?:\[?([^\]\[]+)\]?)+\n` , which should capture lines starting with // and following an optional [ some not bracket characters than a ] , and this could be multiple times before the line ending.

For example `//[a]\n` should result in group `a`, but I would assume `//[b][c]\n` should result group `b` and `c`. But The result is the following instead:

```
Full match: //[b][c]
//[a]

Group 1: a
```

What do I miss? Why Having full match for `[b][c]` doesn't result a group `b` and `c` ?

This is my test code:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "//(?:\\[?([^]\\[]+)\\]?)+\\n";
        final String string = "//[b][c]\n"
                + "//[a]\n"
                + "dfdsfg";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

One more thing, if I remove the optional part for the brackets like this: `"//(?:\\[([^]\\[]+)\\])+\\n"` , then the result is the following:

```
Full match: //[b][c]

Group 1: c
Full match: //[a]

Group 1: a
```

Comment: You should replace `[^]\\[]+` with `[^\\]\\[]+` I believe. You only have 1 group in the pattern, you can't expect two groups in the output.

Comment: According to intellij suggestion the first ] doesn't have to be escaped, but I tried both ways. I expected more groups as the group has + at the end, but I see that in the linked issue that Java cannot handle it, it will just override the result. ( If you closed it with the linked issue, thanks for that, I haven't found it )

Comment: Also,  check https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html, it explains this commonly asked questions.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. As I've seen this is a Java specific problem, C# can iterate over the matches if there are multiple for a single group.

Comment: Yes, .NET regex library and the Python PyPi regex library also allow access to all captures.